# Is there any antivirus software that DOESN'T slow down Time Machine?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, time-capsule, anti-virus

Time Machine making a backup to my TimeCapsule has been extremely slow.

I finally figured out that it was an issue with Avira Antivirus. So I looked for a better software. Seeing the reviews I went for Sophos which is another free software.

What a mistake! Same problem there and some others too.

So, let's forget about free software then, I thought. Let's get the number one software (according to Tom's Hardware) Bitdefender instead! But this time I won't be so naive. I'll do my research first. And after a quick googling I find they have the same problem as the previous to contenders.

So, is there any antivirus software that won't break vital functions for my Mac?

Comment: You don't need antivirus on Mac.

Comment: @IronCraftMan A more coherent inference is: you only need some food, water and appropriate clothing (i.e depending on the climate some wool or a loincloth) ⇒ you don't need a Mac ≈ you don't have a Mac ⇒  you can't install an antivirus app on a Mac you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this fits the ask different format, however, according to [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/news/news-single-view/12-security-suites-for-mac-os-x-put-to-the-test/) (the closest thing to an authority on the subject) BitDefender comes out very high on their scores, especially on the 'slowdown' tests.
I do use it on Windows & it's a lot less irritating than some I could mention.

Avast on the Mac is a known resource hog, btw. I could even feel it on a dual 6-core Mac Pro.
*oops, Avast/Avira... they're both near the bottom of the speed tables, so I'll leave it as is*

Comment: I use BitDefender on my 2015 MBP and I don't notice any slowdown.

Answer (score -1):

I've had some really bad experiences with Bitdefender. They may be good on Windoze, but their Mac version is not "full-featured", and burdened with all sorts of annoying installation issues, non-existent tech support, and other sketchy practices... but I'll stop there.

I've been reasonably happy with Malwarebytes.

Comment: Malwarebytes are never featured in anti-virus comparisons so hard to judge how good they are compared to the excellent Bitdefender. 

How are they sketchy? That would be good to include in your answer since it is an extremely serious accusation. Thanks!

Comment: @MacProGirl: I'm not sure Malwarebytes fits well in the "AV" box. That may explain its omission. And yes, I did make a "serious accusation" because I was trying to give you a genuine answer. Their "sketchy practices" all have to do with how they operate their tech support. Also, certain "features" in their software simply **never worked**. I don't think I should get into a lot of detail here as this is not a discussion forum. But yeah - I wouldn't have said it unless it was my experience - and it was.